# Android M and Device Admin Applications

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, device-admin, android-security

I have a device admin application that supports android devices with API 8+.

I am checking how the changes of Android M might affect my current application. It turned out now the user has the option to turn off certain permissions even though device admin has been already activated.

Isn't there any way to disallow that for device admin apps?